# "e and a" as combinations of pi bonds

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, solid-state-chemistry

I am trying to get a better intuition on solid-state physics but I am a chemist by degree. I came across this [article](https://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/hughbanks/courses/673/handouts/hoffmann.pdf) that attempts to bridge the gap between solid-state physics and molecular chemistry. However, I am unsure what the author is referring to when he says "a and an e combination". I believe it is talking about the symmetry of the pi orbitals but I really have no clue.

[image: image regarding the excerpt I am referring to]

Comment: A is symmetric with respect to the principal axis, e is degenerated. You may want to look at character tables.

Comment: They are called Mulliken symbols or Mullikan notation if you try read more about it.